# Unity NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development, photon

Every time I click play in Unity, I get this error.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
LobbyManager.PlayerCountUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/Lobby/LobbyManager.cs:213)
LobbyManager.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Lobby/LobbyManager.cs:209)
```

I have tried the following to ensure the **ERROR does not pop up**:

1. I have ensured the inspector with public variables has been allocated with the assigned GameObject.
2. I tried changing `roomSize = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.MaxPlayers;` to the start function since its not a variable which require updating but the error still pops up!

Here is My code:

```
public int playerCount;
int roomSize;


private void Update()
{
    //minimum of 2 players in the room && the player who is clicking the start button is the masterclient
    if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient && PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount >= 2)
    {
        playButton.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        playButton.SetActive(false);
    }

    PlayerCountUpdate();
}
public void PlayerCountUpdate()
{
    roomSize = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.MaxPlayers;
    playerCount = PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length;
    roomCountDisplay.text = playerCount + " / " + roomSize;
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: this line  `roomSize = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.MaxPlayers;`

Comment: CurrentRoom is likely null then.  Are you sure you are in a room at this point?

Comment: ohh yeah i understand what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: I've figured  away to solve this, i called the current room which was null!